# Attempting create bar charts form a Pandas Data Frame. Charts to be specific to the month

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Dataframe contains essentially three things.

Date, Count, and Company.

I want to create a program that makes bar charts with count on the y axis and company on the x axis; but there should be multiple charts for different months. for.eg there should be a may chart containing all the companies counts from that month only

Ive tried using groupby to organise them by company and using `.sum()` to count up for the whole database per company but am not able to do it also specific to a month

I can group them by company but I want to create individual graphs per company and also by month

```
Metric  Count   Date
Apple   97  16/01/2019
Samsung 84  06/01/2019
Linux   100 03/02/2019
Microsoft   61  29/01/2019
Blackberry  17  24/02/2019
LG  98  23/02/2019
Panasonic   20  22/02/2019
Apple   100 19/03/2019
Samsung 43  02/01/2019
Linux   21  06/01/2019
Microsoft   72  05/03/2019
Blackberry  75  24/03/2019
LG  82  19/03/2019
Panasonic   42  25/02/2019
Apple   50  12/01/2019
Samsung 74  15/02/2019
Linux   41  09/03/2019
Microsoft   97  12/03/2019
Blackberry  15  28/03/2019
```

I can group them by company but I want to create individual graphs per company and also by month

```
df = pd.read_csv('values.csv', delimiter = ',')
df.head(1)
df = df.query('Metric == "Company"')
df = df.groupby('Company').sum().Count    
print(df)

df = df.plot(kind='bar', align='center', title ="entity",figsize=(15,10),legend=True, fontsize=5)
df.set_ylabel("Count",fontsize=12)
df.set_xlabel("Company",fontsize=12)
```

I can group them by company but I want to create individual graphs per company and also by month

Comment: So you want a plot for each month, where `x` is the company, and `y` is the total count?

Comment: yes very much so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data['Date']= pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
data['Month']=data['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')
df = data.groupby(['Month', 'Metric']).sum()
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

It gives the output as below.

[image]

One plot for each month could be plotted with the code below

```
data['Date']= pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
data['Month']=data['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')
df = data.groupby(['Month', 'Metric']).sum()
months = df.index.levels[0]
for month in months:
    data = df.loc[month]
    data.plot(kind='bar', align='center', title =str(month), legend=True)
```

Comment: Hi, thxs for your response, Im getting a value error for some reason and it states "ValueError: month must be in 1..12"

Comment: @ritzrori. Try the update. We need to specify the format of your input.

Comment: Hi im able to print them out now but any idea how to print the graphs independent of the month so like 1 graph for each month

Comment: Use the for loop as suggested by Juan. I have updated the solution with the additional code as well.

Comment: Hi thxs so much its now returning a key error "Jan" when it begins the loop

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
new_df = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'])
            .Count.sum()
         )

(new_df.reset_index()
       .groupby('Date')
       .plot.bar(x='Metric', y='Count',subplots=True)
)
```

Comment: Hi, thxs for your input, Im getting an awful lot of syntax errors and Im not able to see why the error us there. Do you mind running it and see if it returns anything there

Comment: You should first change `Date` column to datetime by `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`.

Comment: Hi sorry I should have been much more clear, my format is actually in YY-MM-DD sorry

Comment: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Hik, Ive just implement that but its now returning an object error on the new_df line #your first line. This is my current code: df = pd.read_csv('values.csv', delimiter = ',')


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

new_df = df.groupby[pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='m')].Count.sum()

new_df = new_df.reset_index().groupby('Date').plot.bar(x='Metric', y='Count',subplots=True)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a 'Month' column and group by month and metric:

```
import datetime

# New month column
month_key = lambda x: datetime.date(x.year, x.month, 1)
df['Month'] = df['Date'].apply(month_key)

# Group by month and metric
df = df.groupby(['Month', 'Metric']).sum()

# One plot for each month
months = df.index.levels[0]

for month in months:
    data = df.loc[month]
    data.plot(kind='bar', align='center', title =str(month), legend=True)
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason its returning an attribute error around the line month_key = lambda x : ...

Comment: Is your 'Date' column in datetime format? Try adding parse_dates=['Date'] to the arguments on read_csv.

Comment: Hi sorry I should have been much more clear, my format is actually in YY-MM-DD sorry